# Identify sequences between identical values

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

I have a large matrix:

```
id    v1   v2   v3   v4   v5   v6   v7   v8
1001   37   15   30   37    4   11   35   37
2111   44   31   44   30   24   39   44   18
3121   43   49   39   34   44   43   26   24
4532   45   31   26   33   12   47   37   15
5234   23   27   34   23   30   34   23    4
6345   9    46   39   34    8   43   26   24
```

For each row (id), I would like to identify intervals of numbers in column v1 to v8. An interval is here defined as a sequence of numbers which starts and ends with the same number.

For example, in the first row, there are two sequences which both start and ends with 37: From column 1 to 4 (**37**, 15, 30, **37**) and from column 4 to column 8 (**37**, 4, 11, 35, **37**).

The focal value should only occur in start and end positions. For example, in the first row, the sequence from 37 at V1, to 37 at V8 is *not* included, because 37 also occurs in V4.

For each interval, I want the index of the start and end columns, the focal start and end value, and the sequence of numbers in between.

Desired output:

```
1001 [v1] to [v4] 37 to 37: 15,30
1001 [v4] to [v8] 37 to 37: 4, 11, 35
2111 [v1] to [v3] 44 to 44: 31 
2111 [v3] to [v7] 44 to 44: 30, 24, 39
```

Any suggestions? Algorithm?

I managed to code for the indices for a vector not a matrix,

```
a <- which(x == 37)
from <- a[!(a-1) %in% a]
to <- a[!(a+1) %in% a]
rbind(from, to)
```

Comment: Try `apply(mat, 1, function(x) tapply(x, cumsum(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)), FUN = tail, -1))`

Comment: @akrun; thank you is there a way to export a big list into a csv file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very brute-force method. Get unique elements for the given row, check if they are present more than once but not side-by-side, then `lapply` through each, getting the elements of the row `x` between them.

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  u <- u[sapply(u, function(u) any(diff(which(x == u)) > 1))]
  lapply(setNames(u, u), function(u){ 
      ind <- which(x == u)
      lapply(seq(length(ind) - 1), 
             function(i) x[seq(ind[i] + 1, ind[i + 1] - 1)])
  })
})
```

Output:

```
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`37`
# [[1]]$`37`[[1]]
# [1] 15 30
# 
# [[1]]$`37`[[2]]
# [1]  4 11 35
# 
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$`44`
# [[2]]$`44`[[1]]
# [1] 31
# 
# [[2]]$`44`[[2]]
# [1] 30 24 39
# 
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$`43`
# [[3]]$`43`[[1]]
# [1] 49 39 34 44
# 
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# named list()
# 
# [[5]]
# [[5]]$`23`
# [[5]]$`23`[[1]]
# [1] 27 34
# 
# [[5]]$`23`[[2]]
# [1] 30 34
# 
# 
# [[5]]$`34`
# [[5]]$`34`[[1]]
# [1] 23 30
# 
# 
# 
# [[6]]
# named list()
```

Edit: Henrik's answer inspired me to do a join-based version

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

d <- melt(as.data.table(m), "id", variable.name = 'ci')[, ci := rowid(id)]

setorder(d, id) 
options(datatable.nomatch = 0)

d[d, on = .(id, value, ci > ci)
  , .(id, value, i.ci, x.ci)
  , mult = 'first'] %>% 
  .[d, on = .(id, i.ci < ci, x.ci > ci)
    , .(id, value, from_ci = x.i.ci, to_ci = x.x.ci, i.value)] %>% 
  .[, .(val = .(i.value))
    , by = setdiff(names(.), 'i.value')]


#      id value from_ci to_ci         val
# 1: 1001    37       1     4       15,30
# 2: 1001    37       4     8     4,11,35
# 3: 2111    44       1     3          31
# 4: 2111    44       3     7    30,24,39
# 5: 3121    43       1     6 49,39,34,44
# 6: 5234    23       1     4       27,34
# 7: 5234    34       3     6       23,30
# 8: 5234    23       4     7       30,34
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` alternative.

Convert matrix to data.table and `melt` to long format. Create a column index 'ci' to keep track of the original columns (`rowid(id)`). Order by 'id'.

For each 'id' and 'value' (`by = .(id, value)`), check if number of rows is larger than one (`if(.N > 1)`), i.e. if there is at least one sequence. If so, grab the row index (`.I`) of the sequences and their column indexes (in the original data). For each sequence, grab the corresponding values between start and end index. Wrap in `list` twice (`.(.(`)  to create a list column.

```
library(data.table)
d <- melt(as.data.table(m), id.vars = "id")
d[ , `:=`(
  ci = rowid(id),
  variable = NULL)]  
setorder(d, id)

d2 <- d[ , if(.N > 1){
  .(from = .I[-.N], to = .I[-1],
    from_ci = ci[-.N], to_ci = ci[ -1])
}, by = .(id, value)]

d2[ , val := .(.(d$value[seq(from + 1, to - 1)])), by = 1:nrow(d2)]
d2[ , `:=`(from = NULL, to = NULL)]

#      id value from_ci to_ci         val
# 1: 1001    37       1     4       15,30
# 2: 1001    37       4     8     4,11,35
# 3: 2111    44       1     3          31
# 4: 2111    44       3     7    30,24,39
# 5: 3121    43       1     6 49,39,34,44
# 6: 5234    23       1     4       27,34
# 7: 5234    23       4     7       30,34
# 8: 5234    34       3     6       23,30
```

Comment: massive thank you for your help; the code is running thank you; what I again fail to do is to export the result in csv or table. If I export d2 I receive only the first row. What I am misisng? Could you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Did it work? I generally prefer to keep my data in a tidy, long format, rather than having list columns. So you may replace the last step with `d2[ , .(id = id, value = value, from_ci = from_ci, to_ci = to_ci, val = d$value[seq(from + 1, to - 1)]), by = 1:nrow(d2)]`

Comment: @Henrik- yes it does; thanks, what I am trying now is to save the result in a file. Yes, I tried to export a list but it did not worked. I will try your new suggestion

Comment: Another possibility could be to concatenate the values in 'val' column to a string. Perhaps OK in the end for printing in a report, but useless otherwise, i.e. if you want to process the values further. Anyway: `d2[ , val := .(toString(d$value[seq(from + 1, to - 1)])), by = 1:nrow(d2)]`. Again, _if_ you are going to process your data further, at least `data.table` is much happier with long, tidy data, rather than list columns.